# How to Make server side lable visible false from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following lable

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="ControlWidth"></asp:Label>
```

Which is visible false. On button Save if there is any error on page I make it visible and show error msg.

On Cancel button I am clearing the text of this lable thorugh Javascript as

```
  var lblErrorMessage = document.getElementById('<%=lblErrorMessage.ClientID%>');

  lblErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
  lblErrorMessage.innerText = "";
```

But when I do some other opration on page that time page get postback and error message

Which I have cleared get visible.

Can anyone tell me how I can make label Visible false through javascript and which should

not get visible on postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid this problem altogether, have your `cancel` button do a postback and clear the label values and set its visibility to false again fron the server side as opposed to doing it from the client side. The reason this is happening is because even though you clear the label innerText and innerHtml with javascript; the ViewState still contains the old values so when you post back; it recovers those values.

If you think you can leave without ViewState being enabled for the wrror label, you could disable it and the problem will go away; for example:

```
<asp:label id="errorlabel" EnableViewState="false" />
```

Comment: I have following <asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Labels,CancelButton%>" Width="90" Height="20" OnClientClick="return btnCancel_ClientClick()"/> and its requirement to do clear from client side only....so any other solution ?

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh disable ViewState on the label. `<asp:label id="errorlabel" EnableViewState="false" />` if it doesn't work, I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh wonderful, please accept the answer when you have a chance.